# For loop with Python to iterate through a grouped DF and extract the top value for each group and append to a new DF?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a dataset (df) of the US presidential election results from 2000-2020 that breaks down how many votes each party got within each state (so for arguments sake: 3 parties [Dem, Rep, Other], 51 voting districts [DC included], and 6 presidential elections = 918 rows of data).

I am trying to get a single line for each state/year combination that corresponds to the party that won that state (i.e., 51 districts * 6 years = 306 lines of data).

I grouped df by 'year' and 'state' and sorted by highest vote count so the data looks how I want it to in terms of sorting. Now I want to extract the first line (ie the party that got the highest vote in that state in that year) and append it to a new df2.

I wrote this line of code which shows me the values that I'm looking to extract, but I'm not sure how to append it to a new DF (screenshot of the output is attached).

`df.groupby(by = ['year', 'state'])['candidatevotes'].max()`

I cheated a bit and asked ChatGPT but it didn't provide me with a great output. Here's the code it gave me and I'll attach a screenshot of the output.

```
# Group the 'state_group' DataFrame by 'year'
grouped = state_group.groupby('year')
# Loop through each year group
for year, group_df in grouped:
    # Group the year group by 'state'
    state_grouped = group_df.groupby('state_po')
    
    # Loop through each state group
    for state, state_group_df in state_grouped:
        # Find the index of the row with the party having the highest vote
        max_vote_index = state_group_df['candidatevotes'].idxmax()
        
        # Extract the row with the party of the highest vote
        winner_row = state_group_df.loc[max_vote_index]
        
        # Append the winner row to the 'state_winners' DataFrame
        state_winners = state_winners.append(winner_row)

# Reset the index of the 'state_winners' DataFrame
state_winners.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Print the 'state_winners' DataFrame
print(state_winners)
```

I'm just looking for a general starting point and if even doing a for loop is the right approach for this. I've tried running the loop code when the data was grouped, then tried when the data was ungrouped (screenshots are when I ungrouped the data), tried it when it was in a MultiIndex with year and state as the indexes, etc. If there's a simpler way to extract the data I'm looking for, that'd be even better.

[This is what the data itself looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkyW3.png)

[This is essentially the data I would like to extract and append to a new df, obviously with the entire row of data intact (i.e., all original columns, not just the raw data values)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFhe8.png)

[This is the output for the code ChatGPT provided me with. I'm not even sure how the output was nearly 6x the number of rows as the original dataset.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6kho.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always avoid using `.apply` where you can, as this is very inefficient.  Instead you can just `.groupby` and take the highest valued row in `"candidatevotes"` by sorting first:

```py
state_winners = df.sort_values("candidatevotes").groupby(["year", "state_po"], as_index=False).last()
```

As the default sorting order is `ascending=True`, using `.last()` will return the last row of the grouped data, which will be the row with the highest number of candidate votes.  Similarly, you could use `.first()` if you were sorting in descending order.

Using `as_index=False` in the `.groupby` means that the two columns used for grouping are not used as the index, but are instead columns.

**Note:** if there are two rows with equal `"candidatevotes"` then only one will be returned (similar to the answer by @eduarokapp).  Although this is unlikely to occur with candidate votes, it is something to be aware of.

Here are some time comparisons between the above and the answer by @eduardokapp (over x7 faster when I run this):

```py
# without `.apply`
%timeit df.sort_values("candidatevotes").groupby(["year", "state_po"], as_index=False).last()
# 3.67 ms ± 118 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# with `.apply`
%timeit df.groupby(['year', 'state_po']).apply(lambda group: group.loc[group['candidatevotes'].idxmax()])
# 27.2 ms ± 338 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you! And a little more simple as well. I appreciate the tip on efficiency comparison between using .apply vs not.  Clearly forgot about that very simple .last() method lol... Thanks again

Comment: No problem!  A lot is possible to complete without `.apply`, but sometimes there may not be any more efficient alternatives and a loop would be required anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more complex groupby, like so:

```py
state_winners = df.groupby(['year', 'state_po']).apply(lambda group: group.loc[group['candidatevotes'].idxmax()]
```

What this code is doing is grouping by year and state_po then making applying an anonymous (lambda) function to each group. The function takes the group and returns only the row where group['candidatevotes'] is max.

I recommend you taking a look at the [pandas groupby function documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), it has some nice examples of its applications.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I plugged that in and received the error: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds. But I changed 'iloc' to 'loc' and that seemed to fix the error. And I appreciate your explanation of lambda. I've seen that on SO a few times, but that wasn't covered in the Udemy Python course I took so that was really helpful. Definitely will be using in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough rep to upvote your comment lol. But one last question, if I try to change the original df to a multiindex (i.e., based on year and state), the groupby that you provided, it just returns my original df with the same # of rows and columns and everything. So my question is: is it best practice to use the groupby function on a normal dataframe where the index is not manipulated (i.e., the standard python index of 0 - n)? I see that your function returns a multiindex df, so I assume the answer is yes that the original df needs to be a normal df with a normal index?

Comment: I think so! I particularly am not a big fan of multiindexes, so I'll just `.reset_index(drop=False)` them, so they become regular columns!